# Can i create a corda state with null party?

Tags: corda

I want to create a corda state where one of the party fields should be empty initially. In next flow, I want to update that party field.

But when I create the first flow, during tx.verify(), its throwing error as 
Malformed transaction, OUTPUTS_GROUP at index 0 cannot be deserialized.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is working fine for me in Corda 3.

Here's my state:

```
class MyState(val party: Party?) : ContractState {
    override val participants: List<AbstractParty> get() = listOf()
}
```

And here's my flow:

```
@InitiatingFlow
@StartableByRPC
class Initiator : FlowLogic<Unit>() {
    override val progressTracker = ProgressTracker()

    @Suspendable
    override fun call() {
        val myState = MyState(null)
        val txCommand = Command(MyContract.Commands.Command(), ourIdentity.owningKey)

        val notary = serviceHub.networkMapCache.notaryIdentities[0]
        val txBuilder = TransactionBuilder(notary)
                .addOutputState(myState, MY_CONTRACT_ID)
                .addCommand(txCommand)

        // Verifying the builder.
        txBuilder.verify(serviceHub)

        // Verifying the signed transaction.
        serviceHub.signInitialTransaction(txBuilder).verify(serviceHub)
    }
}
```

Verifying either the builder or the signed transaction causes no issues. This is true in both Kotlin and Java.

Comment: No problem. Let me know if you track down the original cause of the issue!

Comment: Issue was the state field was declared as not null.